# How to append embed code to youtube anchor link

Tags: php, regex, youtube, preg-replace

I use this code to make urls clickable as anchor links in forum posts.

```
function makelink($str) {

    $str = preg_replace_callback('/((((http)(s)?:\/\/)|www\.)[-0-9æøåa-zA-Z?-??-?\(\)%_+\.~#?&;:@\/\/=]+)(?<!\.)/i', function($matches) {
        if (strtolower(substr($matches[0], 0 , 4)) == 'www.') {
            $matches[0] = 'http://' . $matches[0];
        }
        return '<a href="'.$matches[0].'" title="link" rel="noreferrer">'.$matches[0].'</a>';
    }, $str);
    
    return trim($str);

}
```

It works fine. Now I need to also make youtube links into embed codes underneath the link (appended to the link I guess).

It's ok for this that there is an extra replacement routine going on.

How could I make some code that replaces the resulting anchor (if it's a youtube link):

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOLAy72Tv24" title="link" rel="noreferrer">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOLAy72Tv24</a>
```

With this:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOLAy72Tv24" title="link" rel="noreferrer">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOLAy72Tv24</a>
<br />
<iframe class="youtube" width="350" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LOLAy72Tv24/" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So it just needs to take the video id and put out embed code underneath the original link, while outputting both together.

Comment: Use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to determine if the url host is YouTube and if so, append what you need.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks. But I'm a bit at loss as to how to code just the replacement/append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my proposed solution:

```php
function makelink($str) {
    $pattern = '/((((http)(s)?:\/\/)|www\.)[-0-9æøåa-zA-Z?-??-?\(\)%_+\.~#?&;:@\/\/=]+)(?<!\.)/i';
    $str = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) {
        if (strtolower(substr($matches[0], 0 , 4)) == 'www.') {
            $matches[0] = 'http://' . $matches[0];
        }
        // store anchor tag html in a variable instead of returning immediately
        $html = '<a href="'.$matches[0].'" title="link" rel="noreferrer">'.$matches[0].'</a>';
        if (isYouTubeVideoUrl($matches[0])) {
            $html .= '<br />'.makeiFrame($matches[0]);
        }
        return $html;
    }, $str);

    return trim($str);
}

function isYouTubeVideoUrl(string $url): bool
{
    return (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) === 'www.youtube.com' || isYouTubeShortUrl($url))
        && strpos(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), 'v=') !== false;
}

function isYouTubeShortUrl(string $url): bool
{
    return parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) === 'youtu.be';
}

function makeiFrame(string $url): string {
    $embedUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.getYouTubeVideoId($url).'/';
    return '<iframe class="youtube" width="350" height="250" src="'.$embedUrl.'" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}

function getYouTubeVideoId(string $url): string
{
    if (isYouTubeShortUrl($url)) {
        preg_match('/[^\/]+$/', $url, $matches);
        return $matches[0];
    }

    preg_match('/(?<=v=)(.*?)(?=(&|$))/', $url, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

It is designed to work both with regular YouTube URLs (`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOLAy72Tv24`) and short YouTube URLs (`https://youtu.be/LOLAy72Tv24`). It also supports the `v` parameter being anywhere in the query string for regular URLs.

Most of the code is pretty straightforward, the key lies in extracting the video id.

Short URLs have the format where the id is behind a slash, so `[^\/]+$` looks for any characters that are not a slash at the end of the string:

- `[^\/]` matches any character not a slash
- `+` is a quantifier for one or more, greedy
- `$` asserts the position at the end of the string

Regular URLs have the format where the id is in a parameter named `v`, so `(?<=v=)(.+?)(?=(&|$))` looks for everything between `v=` and either `&` or the end of the string:

- `(?<=v=)` is a positive lookbehind, assuring that we look for a string right after `v=`
- `(.+?)` matches one or more characters (any, except for line terminators), lazy
- `(?=(&|$))` is a positive lookahead, assuring that we look for a string right before an ampersand (`&`) or the end of a string (`$`)

Comment: The link/url is within text, it's not a static string with just a link/url. Does this account for that?

Comment: I didn't change your `makelink` function apart from adding the code that appends the `iframe`. It is still responsible for extracting `url`s from text. My code just continues its work after your code found a `url` match in the text.

Comment: Hi again. It seems to work well, thank you. But if the url is to main website youtube.com (no video, just link to youtube) it triggers an offset error. Any way to avoid that? Maybe so it only triggers embed etc. if there is video id

Comment: Perhaps I will just throw in some "check for id" in the isYouTubeUrl() function

Comment: @mowgli I've modified the code to account for that (for any future readers). I've also renamed the function from `isYouTubeUrl` to `isYouTubeVideoUrl`, to reflect what it checks more accurately. The only thing I don't know is if short urls can be of something else than a video (I've looked around a channel and haven't found an option). If it proves so, then you'd have to account for that too.

Comment: Great work, I really appreciate it. And I think some others can find use in it too